# jQuery hover over parent but not children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there anyway to interact with the DOM using jQuery that when a user hovers over a div a menu appears, but when they hover over a particular child element inside that parent, nothing happens?

**Code so far**

```
$('#player_area:not(< #player_links)').live("mouseenter", function() {
  return $('#album_tracks').slideDown(200);
}).live("mouseleave", function() {
  return $('#album_tracks').hide();
});
```

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` should work like you want it to.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q4beS/2/

Comment: Mmh, when I remove the `<` it seems to work (`<` is not a valid selector anyway). Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/q4beS/4/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what you need : http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

`mouseenter` and `mouseleave` method.

Check the example demo ;)

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether it is because you do not wish the action to be repeated with mouseenter events on the children. That is the event is already triggered by the parent and you don't want it to be performed again without first leaving the parent or whether you want the child to not trigger the mouseenter (if it has been positioned outside of the parent).

It seems that your code should work if you merely remove the :not selector.

Edit... Sorry misunderstood... The following fiddle should address what you needed to do

http://jsfiddle.net/q4beS/6/

Comment: to answer your question; yes, I only want the action to take place on the parent directly, if the mouse "enters" or "hovers" over the child within the parent, then nothing happens or if the album_tracks div is visible, then hide the div

Comment: I ended up simplifying almost all of my code. I was able to utilize another div class that was in place for the parent hover event. I simply just separated out the child from the parent and repositioned everything and it all works nicely :)